# Q-Learning: Should I give the sink states a reward, or a Q-value?

Tags: machine-learning, q-learning

I'm implementing Q-learning via neural network to learn the game of Othello/Reversi.

Currently, a win gives a reward of 1, a lose gives -1.  However, I've run into a dilemma.

I don't know whether I should implement this value as a reward or as an initial Q-value, or if it even matters.  Let me explain:

Option 1: Initialize ALL Q-values randomly (or maybe to 0), even in states that are a Win or a Lose.  The Win/Lose values will come from the Reward aspect of Q-learning.  So a Win/Lose state has no higher/lower initial value than any other state, but once you get there its reward is propagated backwards.

Option 2:  Initialize all Q-values randomly (or 0) EXCEPT for winning/losing states, which get initialized to the Win or Lose value.  There is no reward, the reward is "built in" to the Q value.  So any action that leads to a Win state always gives Q value of 1, and -1 for transitioning to a Losing state.

Let me give an example for the difference between option 1 and 2.  Say you're doing your first game of learning, and you end up in a state where your set of next moves includes a move that wins the game.

In Option 1, you don't know this, because you are only looking to maximize the Q-value of the next move, and the Q-value of a winning state is initialized the same way as all the other states.  Instead, if you do happen to pick that move, you will get a reward -- but you don't realize you should pick it, so you might not.

In Option 2, you pick it for sure, because it has the highest Q-value possible.

Why I care:

So far I've been doing all Option 1, with poor results.  I tried out Option 2, and it seemed to give much better results, but it could have been an anomaly.  I tried to devise a proof that determines whether it matters, but couldn't think of one.

After thinking about it for a long time I convinced myself that it shouldn't matter.  Even if you don't know from the start that a state is a winning state, once you happen upon it you reinforce the fact that it was a good pick.  But I can't think of why Option 2 seems to be giving consistently better results, so I figured I'd ask smarter people.

My main concern is that Option 2 is much slower, because for every set of next moves I need to check if any of those moves is a winner/loser, which requires an expensive evaluation.  In Option 1, I avoid this evaluation.

Comment: How many Q-values do you have?  It can't be $3^{64}$…

Comment: @NeilG not quite, since not nearly every combination is a legal position.  But the state space is quite large.

Comment: how is that workable?

Comment: @NeilG neural networks and generalization :)

Comment: Anyway, there's no difference between your two methods.  Option 2 is the same as Option 1 after one round of backups.  It is as if you did a backup starting from one step from the goal states.  You could take this idea further and do a set of backups 2 steps from the goal states, etc.  And then process your episodes.